# get taxonomy term count by vid

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have this code which gives me the number of terms on a node

```
 $count = count($node->taxonomy)
```

Is there a way i can restrict this to VID. i only want to get the count for a specific vocabulary.

Oh yeah the site is in D5

here is a link to the page http://national.thedelimagazine.com/8947/delis-austin-issue-2012-pdf-version-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a D5 system handy, but this would do it in D6:

```
$count=0;
foreach ($node->taxonomy as $t) {
  if ($t->vid==VID_IN_QUESTION) {
    $count++;
  }
}
```

and it "should" be the same in D5, but I've said that a lot about D7 and D6 :)  If not,

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($node->taxonomy,true) . '</pre>');
```

should give you the object information you need to modify above to count.  If that doesn't work,

```
$foo=taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($nid, $vid);
$count=count($foo);
```

certainly is a roundabout way of getting them if you already have the node loaded.